# Access 2010 multiple field textbox not showing all

Tags: textbox, ms-access-2010

A textbox in a report I am trying to show properly is hiding multiples, even though the second field is different.

For example: "=[Client] & " " & [Invoice]".

If there is a Bob with multiple invoices, the report will only show one Bob and the lowest invoice number.

How can I make the textbox show every client and invoice individually?
Thanks.

Edit: The SQL requested
"SELECT [SUMFCRR&Plaintiff].Firm, [SUMFCRR&Plaintiff].[Firm Type], IIf([ReportID] Is Null,0,Val([ReportID])) AS [Report #], [SUMFCRR&Plaintiff].SumOfFeesBilled, [SUMFCRR&Plaintiff].[SumOfRecommended Reduction], [SUMFCRR&Plaintiff].[SumOfCosts Billed], [SUMFCRR&Plaintiff].[SumOfCost Reduction], [SumOfFeesBilled]+[SumOfCosts Billed]+[SumOfRecommended Reduction]+[SumOfCost Reduction] AS Reimbursement, [SUMFCRR&Plaintiff].Plaintiff, [SUMFCRR&Plaintiff].ReportID, [SumOfRecommended Reduction]+[SumOfCost Reduction] AS ReductionSum, [SUMFCRR&Plaintiff].Invoice, ([SumOfFeesBilled]+[SumOfRecommended Reduction]) AS FeeReimbursement, ([SumOfCosts Billed]+[SumOfCost Reduction]) AS CostReimbursement, -[SumOfRecommended Reduction] AS PositivefeeReduction, IIf([positivefeereduction]>[sumoffeesbilled] Or [sumofcost reduction]>[sumofcosts billed],"E"," ") AS ErrorNote, -[sumofcost reduction] AS PositveCostReduction
FROM [SUMFCRR&Plaintiff]
WHERE ((([SUMFCRR&Plaintiff].Firm) Like [which firm?] & "*") AND (([SUMFCRR&Plaintiff].ReportID)=[which report?]))
ORDER BY IIf([ReportID] Is Null,0,Val([ReportID]));"

Edit2: The two fields of concern here are [Plaintiff] and [Invoice], and all information is shown when I run the query itself.

Comment: Please update your Original post with the SQL you are using for the report.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.  It was originally in the [Plaintiff] grouping.  I changed the group to [Invoice], and the multiple invoice numbers started showing.